# session_start() function is very slower on HHVM than php5 or php7

Tags: php, session, performance-testing, hhvm, php-7.1

for this simple code:

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);

session_start();
echo session_id();

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = ($time_end - $time_start)*1000;
echo "<br> Time to get uid: $time milliseconds";

?>
```

When I run it in php7 or php5 with Apache server, the run time is around one millisecond but my machine with HHVM takes 60-100ms to execute this. I tried changing the handler to Redis rather than files but got it more than 100ms. I also tried deleting all other sessions, the same. Any idea?

Comment: A single run is meaningless, and runs in dirty environments are meaningless as well. Set up identical, clean machines as a testbed, and then run the test 1000 times minimum.

Comment: I keep refreshing the page with above code and results are similar. Then I keep refreshing the code on other machines and get way different performance time; the difference is a lot, more than 100ms versus less than 1ms!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. In my own system the longer time is due to large variables I saved in my session, while a new session in other systems starts as an empty session.

For future reference, session_start() run-time depends on variables the system needs to load and make them available as a session; so less data you put on your session the faster your overall page speed will be, if you're using sessions in your php code.